# Postgresql/SQL - My date/timestamp logic seems solid but producing nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a massive table full of hospital visit information. Each row corresponds to one visit. The visit/row itself has a unique ID but also contains a person ID (patient) to match back to that persons specific information.

I'm building a "new patient" sequence model. In doing so, I need to remove any patient from the table who has one (or more) visits before a set date. I can't just remove records before that date, as those "loyal patients" will still have visit information.

I tried to build a look-up table with all the patient ID's that have one or more visits before a certain time. I then tried to use this table to remove all visit information for patients who have had one or more visit before that set time.

I've tried multiple variations of the below (with statements, delete statements, having statements ect.) Each time, the final table has no values. I have verified that there are "new patients" with visit dates only after the set date.

My logic feels solid but clearly something is off. Here is the last command I tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
create table client_myvisit_notnew_id as
select patient, admissiondate from client_myvisit_primary_temp1 
where admissiondate < '2015-05-30 00:00:00';

create table client_myvisit_primary_temp2 as
select * from client_myvisit_primary_temp1 
where patient not in
(select patient from client_myvisit_notnew_id);
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your intention, but I *think* you want to delete patients who **do not** have a record **after** '2015-05-30'.

Comment: I want to delete patients who have one or more records before 2015-05-30 but I want to delete all of their records regardless of date. Your comment suggests that maybe I'm going backwards? admissiondate < 2015-05-30 should be all records before that date, correct? I'm trying to gather the patient ID's of everyone before that date and delete any/all of there records from the file.

Comment: Adding relevant table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and your Postgres version would make this a good question. You certainly do not need any temporary tables for your `DELETE` query. Can be done in a single query.

Comment: First question I ever asked Erwin so I'm not surprised I missed a few things but thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not in` is a very dangerous construct with subqueries.  If *any* of the values returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then nothing ever passes the filter.  Although you can fix this by adding a `where` clause, I suggest that you get used to `not exists` instead:

```
select mpt.*
from client_myvisit_primary_temp1  mpt
where not exists (select 1
                  from client_myvisit_notnew_id mni
                  where mpt.patient = mni.patient
                 );
```

This has the semantics that most people expect.

EDIT:

If you just want patients who's original visit is after a certain date, then use window functions:

```
select mpt.*
from (select mpt.*,
             min(mpt.admission_date) over (partition by mpt.patient) as min_ad
      from client_myvisit_primary_temp1
     ) mpt
where min_ad >= '2015-05-30';
```

Defining multiple views is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did not know that "not exists" was better than "not in." That said, after trying this query, I still get these results.
select max(admissiondatetime), min(admissiondatetime) from client_myvisit_primary_temp2;
max = '2016-09-19 00:00:00', min = '2012-07-03 00:00:00';  Any ideas?